# How to add html in calculated column of a list in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, splist

Is there any way to add html in calculated column of a list in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: have a look at this. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218153/sharepoint-online-calculated-fields-pictures

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theTDs = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var i=0;
    var TDContent = " ";
    while (i < theTDs.length) {
        try {
            TDContent = theTDs[i].innerText || theTDs[i].textContent;
            if ((TDContent.indexOf("<div") == 0) && (TDContent.indexOf("</div>") >= 0)) {
            theTDs[i].innerHTML = TDContent;
            }
        }
        catch(err){}
        i=i+1;
    }
});
```